# Laravel print DB sql after preparation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following Laravel, *5.4*, DB query, which generates an error:

```
$item = \DB::select("SELECT :id FROM :tab WHERE :id1 = :value",['id' => $parameters[3],'id1' => $parameters[3],'tab' => $parameters[2],'value' => $value]);
```

I need to know any way that allows me to printout the SQL statement **after** preparation and **before** execution. i.e after supplying the values of the placeholders to understand where is the error comes from.

I tried to use `DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();` like the following:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
                $item = \DB::select("SELECT :id FROM :tab WHERE :id1 = :value",['id' => $parameters[3],'id1' => $parameters[3],'tab' => $parameters[2],'value' => $value]);
                dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

It does not do any thing and sql error like:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE ? = ?'
>   at line 1 (SQL: SELECT :id FROM :tab WHERE :id1 = :value)

Is there any method for the `DB` class that prints the statement with its values? i.e I need to see values instead of `?`

Comment: What version of laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Version 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to post a dump of all the injected parameters to the query, it's probably an empty value or string value without quotes.

In general, I recommend you to work with Laravel's query builder, it's much simpler and its error is more indicative:

```
DB::table($parameters[2])
    ->select([$parameters[3]])
    ->where($parameters[3], $value)
    ->get();
```